# how can i hide a connection in netstat output?

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, proxy, netstat, http-proxy

OS: Windows Server Edition
Basically i want use some other computer's internet connection by making a transparent proxy on target computer.. And i dont want this to be detected...

I have heard that output of netstat can be altered, but how?
Pls help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without patching the kernel or the netstat binary, I don't think you can. This is something rootkits and viruses would really like to do.

(Yes, there might be some ways, but they will probably involve writing a network driver or something.)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you ever want to do this?  What kind of software are you trying to run?

Having said that, the only thing that comes to mind would be to overwrite the preexisting netstat.exe with a new one.

Comment: Actually i will use NTLM server to make proxy and use internet of that machine. And also I dont want the administrator to know that their PC connections is being used through a certain port.